# Add to MSSQL from PDF form

Tags: c#, javascript, sql-server, pdf

I have a PDF form which is used for the purpose of creating inspection reports.
I am currently using a c# WinForms GUI to accept data from users, insert this data into an MSSQL DB, and populate said PDF Form. The latter is achieved using the iTextSharp library.

I have been receiving requests that the process be reversed, whereby, the users enter the data into the form, for a more visually appealing interface, then, through means of a PDF button or something similar, take the data from the form fields in the background, and save it to the DB.
So the flow would be: 
Users populate PDF Form > Button clicked > Data saved to DB > PDF Form saved to local machine.

Can anybody recommend a way of acheiving this? If there is a way of making PDF Buttons invoke C# scripts, that would be ideal, as I could simply have the button save the form, and then invoke a script passing the form filepath as a parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `for a more visually appealing interface` - You're looking for WPF. winforms does not support "visually appealing" stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preference would be to use a web interface or, as HighCore mentioned, WPF.

Acrobat does allow for a database interface with PDF forms.  Look [here at Adobe's website](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/acrobat-forms-form-data-web.html).  The other option is that PDFs support JavaScript so you could use that to post data to a web service.